# Translation plugin with default language?

Tags: plugins, translation, language, customization

I'm running a Wordpress 4.6 site with a modified twenty thirteen theme with content written in French.
I need to setup a translation plugin for my client that would allow anyone to translate a page in English.

The best thing for my clients would be that while modifying a page/article, they would just have to click on a button to switch the page to the english/french version.

The thing is, I need the plugin to recognize a "default" language (here being French), to make it that if a page is not translated yet, it just shows up the French version.

I've been testing out many plugins, but not one seems to work the way I need so far.

**EDIT : I also need the titles on my navbar to be translated.**

Comment: You should try the plugin [MultilingualPress](https://multilingualpress.org/), two different posts for different languages, but you can edit all languages in an UI or switch to other edit screen. Also much more, but read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed a trilingual website, and used a plugin named [Polylang](http://www.polylang.pro). It will work perfect for your wanted result, even though it may require some time to set up and get going.